# Preposition: Pay attention in your studies

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I think the usual way to say it is:

> Pay attention **to** your studies.

But is it also acceptable to use **in**?

> Pay attention **in** your studies.

Comment: “Attention” is generally “paid _to”_ some direct object in a sentence, which is why the first works so well. The second is valid also, but is less natural because it attaches the sense of the stand-alone phrase “Pay attention.” to “studies” which itself would probably then be interpreted as “the act of studying”. It would be understood as “Exhibit attentiveness during your studying” making it slightly different in meaning (in my opinion) from the first (which would be something more like “Attend to your education.”)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are structurally different:

1. > Pay [ attention to your studies ].

   Here, *pay* is a transitive verb taking the noun *attention* as a direct object.  The noun *attention* can take a preposition phrase (PP) as a complement, and specifically it selects a PP headed by *to*.  The resulting string of words *pay attention to* is a collocation (meaning people say it a lot), so it sounds very natural.
2. > [ Pay attention ] in your studies.

   Again, *pay* is a transitive verb taking the noun *attention* as a direct object.  The noun *attention*, however, does **not** take a PP complement in this example.  Instead, the following PP is a domain adjunct, which means it limits the domain of the verb.  In this case, *pay attention* is limited to the domain *in your studies*.  Since it's an adjunct rather than a complement, it's not limited to beginning with a particular preposition, and *in* is okay.  But since the resulting string of words *pay attention in* isn't as common as the collocation *pay attention to*, it doesn't sound as natural.

Ultimately, they both mean about the same thing, but they're grammatically somewhat different.  Of the two examples, the first one sounds more natural.